# Book with vslam

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, robotics

I am looking for a book where some monocular/visual SLAM is described and implemented.

Can you list and recommend some?

I'd like to use OpenCV but that is not a requirement.

Comment: This question has been answered but a _book_ is still desired. If you know one add an answer, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a book with a description of such an algorithm, but there's a complete open source implementation (in C++) of a vslam system available as part of the Robot Operating System. It uses SURF descriptors and vocabulary trees for place recognition, and bundle adjustment for SLAM. It does use OpenCV heavily as it's made by the same people. See the website [here.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam) I can't say for sure as they don't mention and I haven't looked in great detail, but their implementation seems to be based on, or at least is similar to, [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4648456) paper.

Edit: The paper linked above was actually written by the people who implemented the vslam system given above, it appears. So it is definitely a good resource for understanding it.

Comment: Thanks, that paper looks good. I'm still looking for some explanation with a "teaching-focus" (rather than a "That's what we did"-focus) but for now I'll close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a book, but maybe [PTAM](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gk/PTAM/) can be useful. The [ISMAR 2007 paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ISMAR.2007.4538852) by Klein has a description about the system and the **source code is available** so you can check the details.

Of course, PTAM is just a (good) method in the SLAM field.

Comment: Here is a proper (i.e. available to all) link for that paper: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gk/publications/KleinMurray2007ISMAR.pdf

Comment: @TH I am looking at a book. I'd like some sample implementation with pseudo code (or not) that is explained. All those various research papers tend to be sparse in detail. Also, I won't look at their source code because I want to be able to use and modify my program freely.